# Find the orthogonal projection of $v=\begin{pmatrix} 4 \cr -6 \cr -6 \end{pmatrix}$ onto the line L

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

**The problem**

Find the orthogonal projection of $v=\begin{pmatrix} 4 \cr -6 \cr -6 \end{pmatrix}$ onto the line L through  $v=\begin{pmatrix} 8 \cr -2 \cr -5 \end{pmatrix}$ and the origin.

**What I've done so far**

$$\operatorname{Proj}_L(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}} \mathbf{v}$$

So, in this case, we have

$$\mathbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix}4\\-6\\-6\end{pmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix}8\\-2\\-5\end{pmatrix},$$

so that

$$\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{x} = 4 \cdot 8 -6 \cdot -2 - 6 \cdot -5 = 74, \quad \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v} = 4^2 - 6^2 - 6^2 = -56,$$

hence

$$\operatorname{Proj}_L(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{74}{-56}\begin{pmatrix}4\\-6\\-6\end{pmatrix}.$$

Am I right so far with this? Would I need to go further, with the following:

$$\operatorname{Refl}_L(\mathbf{x}) = 2\operatorname{Proj}_L(\mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{x} = 2\frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}} \mathbf{v} - \mathbf{x},$$

which yields

$$\operatorname{Refl}_L(\mathbf{x}) = 2 \cdot \frac{74}{-56}\begin{pmatrix}4\\-6\\-6\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}8\\-2\\-5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-130\\125\\146\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Didn't you lose the denominator in the last equation? Also $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}=4^2−6^2−6^2$ should be $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}=4^2+(−6)^2+(−6)^2$. The correct answers are [here](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/7/MyrbaREfXDIhqrbkqgDwLHV0jHV1TIK/AylajTK9CUx9IlmlqlVlzBRRl5pVEF8TCWEZaBboVsf//AwA).

Comment: Thanks! Which pair of answers would they be? All four items?

Comment: What four items? `Print[p]` prints projection $\left(\frac{37}{11}, -\frac{111}{22}, -\frac{111}{22}\right)^T$ and `Print[2*p-x]` prints reflection.

Comment: Thanks! That's fantastic. Apologies, for my muddled response, but your prints reflection and prints projection explanation was exactly what I was looking for!